# Space at edges in all browsers, HTML?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

This has been annoying me for a while yet the solution must be really simple. If I create a basic page and add `<p>test</p>`, it doesn't stay to the exact top of the page, or left. Instead it seems to be padded about 10px. I've tried it in a div with `margin: 0px; padding: 0px;` however that didn't work.

Help is appriciated! :)

Comment: Google for a *CSS reset*. Use it wisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give **"<body>**" zero margin and padding, too

```
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
...
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

The html page by default has a 10 pixel margin. Try this:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add those settings to the body of the page:

```
body
{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What they said. Also, there is a default `line-height`, which is usually 120% of the font size. So with a font size of 20 pixels, you still have 4 pixels of "padding" to cope with (2 pixels above, 2 below), even if all the `padding`s are zero. To rectify, set `line-height` to `1`.